# Id of the src Image Inside the ImageView

Tags: android

Basically i am working on app like game and I have 20 Images from which one will be set as the Image "src". I want to know is it possible to get the Id of the Image inside the `ImageView`? but not the Id of the `ImageView`. Because when i use Click Listener it gives me the id of the

```
//your idea of imageView.setTag() and view.getTag() is better but Now i want     to do this in the loop. Is it possible?    
int id1 = R.drawable.img1;    
imageView1.setTag(id1);    
int id2 = R.drawable.img2    
imageView2.setTag(id2);    
// and similarly for 20 ImageView
```

Comment: And AFAIK the answer for your question is no. After setting the image with image id you cannot retrieve it from ImageView again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTag() and getTag for adding and getting reference in a View.

To set Reference
get all image id's & imageviewids id's in an array loop as follows

```
    int imageid[] = new int[] { R.drawable.imageView1, R.drawable.imageView2,... };
    int imageviewid[] = new int[]{R.id.imageView1, R.id.imageView2,...}; 
    for(int i=0;i<imageid.length;i++){
    ImageView imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(imageviewid[i]);
    imageView.setTag(imageid[i]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageid[i]);
    }
```

To get Reference

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
    String clickedItem =(String) v.getTag(); 
}
```

Edit: To set Tag on Xml

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:tag="ImageView2"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
android:src="@drawable/img2" />
```

Comment: @SultanAli I don't understand your question! what do you want to do?

Comment: basically i have 20 images and 20 imageView. 
i want to get the id of image ( int id = R.drawable.image1) and set this id as the tag of my ImageView (ImageView1.setTag(id);) for 20 Images and 20 ImageView throw a loop